# Generate a JSON based on SQL query

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Hello I want to generate a JSON output like this

```
{
    "cars": {
        "ferrari": {
           "colors": ["green", "red"]
        },
        "porsche": {
            "colors": ["blue", "yellow"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 Mysql tables:

```
cars: (id, name) and colors: (id, color, brand_id)
```

The only way I know is for example

```
SELECT * FROM brands
and then...
SELECT * FROM colors WHERE car_id = ? 
to get all the cars colors
```

It is possible to do that in only one query?

Comment: Yes it is. Look into "JOIN SYNTAX" from mysql: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume that car name is the brand. You should do:
cars(id, brand), colors(id, color) and cars_colors(id_brand, id_color) then:
SELECT brand, color FROM (cars JOIN cars_colors ON cars.id = cars_colors.id_brand) JOIN colors ON cars_colors.id_color = colors.id;

Comment: That query will return multiple rows. Looks like I need only two but the colors data array is injected into the colors key. i want to avoid doing this with CODE. But i don`t know if is possible. I experimented using CONCAT() but is not a good choice for performance.

Comment: If you use PHP, you could do a loop on results and do $car = $row["brand"]; array_push($carsColors[$car], $row["color"]); then looping on the array $carsColors to build your JSON. You can do something similar in other languages.

Comment: That is what I want to avoid. And i`m asking for a way to do exactly that with SQL only. thank you